# Ruby Gems Documentation

Tags: ruby, authentication, user-interface, rubygems

I'm just trying to understand how to use particular ruby gems. For example, take this [reddit gem](https://github.com/paradox460/snoo). It says to have this code to start:

```
require 'snoo'

# Create a new instance of the client
reddit = Snoo::Client.new

# Log into reddit
reddit.log_in 'Username', 'Password'

# Send a private message to me (Paradox!)
reddit.send_pm 'Paradox', 'Snoo rubygem rocks!', "Hey Paradox, I'm trying your Snoo rubygem out and it rocks. Thanks for providing such an awesome thing!"

# Log back out of reddit
reddit.log_out
```

Great but in [the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/snoo/0.1.1/frames) you can see that the Client class doesn't have very many exciting functions. The exciting functions are in the Account class but there is no way to get to it...because if I try something like this

```
reddit = Snoo::Account.new
```

I get this error:

```
`initialize': undefined method `new' for Snoo::Account:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Okay so there's no new method but how do I make an `Account` object and use its functions like `log_in`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Snoo::Account` is a Ruby `Module`, and has been mixed in to `Snoo::Client` already by the gem. All the functions of `Snoo::Account` are already available to you on the `reddit` object.

The synopsis documentation in the readme doesn't make this very clear. But otherwise the documentation on the gem looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a short look at the source code on [github](https://github.com/paradox460/snoo/blob/development/lib/snoo.rb) makes me believe this is a fault in the documentation, as client clearly includes the functionality of many other modules, including the Account module you would like to access. In your example code, try the following methods to confirm it for yourself:

```
reddit.methods.sort
reddit.is_a? Snoo::Account
```

I assume the documentation software didn't catch the includes as they were executed using a block.